# Why can I not replace a Dataset using a rule?

Tags: pattern-matching, dataset

Simple replacement of a Dataset object does not seem to follow the expected behavior...

```
Dataset[{}] /. _Dataset->1
```

Returns the empty Dataset not 1 as I would have expected.

Whereas...

```
Hold[Dataset[{}]] /. _Dataset -> 1
```

Returns Hold[1] as expected.

Is this intentional behavior or is the pattern-matcher broken (a bit).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The behaviour we are seeing is due to an up-value on `Dataset`.

Many operators have special meaning when applied to `Dataset`.  They are typically changed so that they operate upon the content of the dataset and then wrap the result back into a dataset.  `ReplaceAll` is one of those operators.  We can see that this special behaviour is implemented as an up-value on `Dataset` by inspecting the output from the following expressions:

```
Dataset;
Debug`$ExamineCode = True;

??Dataset

(* ...
   ReplaceAll[ds_Dataset?Dataset`ValidDatasetQ,rest___] ^:=
     Dataset`EvaluateNormal[ds /. rest]
   ...
*)
```

The unwrapping/wrapping behaviour can be seen by tracing `` Dataset`EvaluateNormal ``, or by inspecting its definition.

The `Hold[...]` variant in the question works because the up-value only applies when `Dataset` is a direct argument to `ReplaceAll`.  Another way to achieve the desired result would be to block the definitions of `Dataset`:

```
Block[{Dataset}, Dataset[{}] /. _Dataset -> 1]

(* 1 *)
```

Comment: More precise it's due to the upvalue with `ReplaceAll`.

Comment: +1. Apparently,  more complex solutions are always late.

Comment: @Szabolcs Good catch.  Fixed.

Comment: WReach & @Leonid - Thanks to both.

Answer (score 8):

#### General

`Dataset` has been internally overloaded on many system functions via `UpValues`. This is necessary to make sure that those functions work on `Dataset` properly, and this behavior may not be the same as would've been by default (without such redefinitions). However, in some cases, this might not be desirable. Below is the code that I suggest to use to selectively disable such redefinitions for any particular function (`ReplaceAll` here).

#### Selective disabling of the `Dataset` integration code - general approach

The following functionality constructs a map `function-name -> positions in Dataset UpValues`:

```
ClearAll[enumerate];
enumerate = Transpose[{#, Range[Length[#]]}] &;

ClearAll[extractHeads];
extractHeads[s_Symbol, prop_: UpValues] := prop[s][[All, 1, 1, 0]];

ClearAll[enumerateHeads];
enumerateHeads[sym_Symbol, prop_: UpValues] :=
  Cases[
    enumerate @ extractHeads[sym, prop], 
    {s_Symbol | s_Symbol[___], p_} :> {s, p}
  ];

ClearAll[groupPairsBy];
groupPairsBy[(which : (First | Last)) -> f_] :=
  Map[f@#[[All, which /. {First -> 2, Last -> 1}]] &]@*GroupBy[which];

ClearAll[$fpositions];
    $fpositions := $fpositions = 
    groupPairsBy[First -> Map[List]]@enumerateHeads[Dataset]
```

You have to run this only once per Mathematica session, and it will be triggered automatically, when `$fpositions` is first called. In particular, it looks like:

```
$fpositions//Short
(* <|Normal->{{1}},Part->{{2}},<<127>>,Join->{{164},{165},{166}},JoinAcross->{{167}}|> *)
```

Here is a generic environment to use, to disable some of the `UpValues`:

```
ClearAll[withUnsetUpvalues];
withUnsetUpvalues[s_Symbol, pos : {{_Integer} ..}] :=
  Function[code, 
    Internal`InheritedBlock[{s},
      With[{protected = Unprotect[s]},
        UpValues[s] = Delete[UpValues[s], pos];
        Protect[protected];
        code
      ]],
    HoldAll];
```

It takes a symbol whose `UpValues` should be disabled, and the list of positions of `UpValues` in the list of all `UpValues`, that must be disabled. It then returns a dynamic environment, in which the code will be executed with those `UpValues` disabled.

Finally, here is the environment generator we want:

```
ClearAll[withDatasetUsualFunctions];
withDatasetUsualFunctions[f_Symbol] := withDatasetUsualFunctions[{f}];
withDatasetUsualFunctions[
   syms : {__Symbol}
] /; AllTrue[syms, KeyExistsQ[$fpositions, #] &] :=
       withUnsetUpvalues[Dataset, Join @@ Lookup[$fpositions, syms]];
```

This generator allows us to create a dynamic environment, where for a group of functions the standard integration code of `Dataset` will be disabled.

#### The case at hand

Here, we want to create the following dynamic environment:

```
withUsualReplaceAll = withDatasetUsualFunctions[ReplaceAll];
```

This has to be done only once per Mathematica session. After that, you can execute any code where you want this altered behavior, inside this environment. In particular:

```
withUsualReplaceAll[Dataset[{}] /. _Dataset -> 1]

(* 1 *)
```

#### Advantages of this method

This method has an advantage over simpler ones (based on `Block` or otherwise), because here you can selectively remove the definitions you are not satisfied with, while all the rest of the `Dataset` machinery will remain usable. With the other methods, you either need special wrappers (like `Hold`) in your code, or have to put up with the fact that usual `Dataset` functionality (queries etc) won't work in some portion of your code (for the method based on `Block`). With the present method however, all you have to do is to wrap your code (or just the top-level function call, since the environment is dynamic), in a dynamic environment, which you define once per Mathematica session with just 1 line of code (well, quite a bit more than one, of course, if we count the code used to define the helper functions above, but that code could be placed into `init.m` file, for example).