# Hold[Dataset[__]] not holding

Tags: bugs, dataset, output

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 11.0.0**

---

With

```
Hold[Dataset[Random[]]]
```

[image]

instead of an expected

> `Hold[Dataset[Random[]]]`

Can `Dataset` expressions be held?

Comment: Related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78131/why-can-i-not-replace-a-dataset-using-a-rule and `Dataset` upvalues but I wasn't able to customize.

Comment: Current use case is generating some documentation that uses held WL commands but can imagine future needs requiring the passing around of Held `Datasets` as per the holding of all other WL expressions.

Comment: `Hold` stops evaluation, but not typesetting (`FormatValues`).

Comment: @ilian in terms of evaluation `ls = {}; held = Hold@Dataset[AppendTo[ls, Random[]]]; SetAttributes[f, HoldAll]; f[x_] := x; f@held` produces three random numbers instead of one random number? in terms of an appearance as a WL command, is there a way of outputting `Dataset[{assocs}]`, verbatim - initial attempts at redefining `Dataset` output via `Format`  as suggested proved unsuccessful and also seems like overkill ...

Comment: Yes, it looks like there is an evaluation leak in the typesetting. Note that `FullForm[f @ held]` is as expected. Would perhaps something like `Inactivate[Dataset[{Random[], Random[]}], Random]` work?

Comment: Also related: [(56246)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56246/121)

Comment: Same thing happens with `Graphics` for the reason given by ilian. Has been a feature of _Mathematica_ since V6 at least.

Comment: @m_goldberg Ok, but feature? ... I can't think of a use-case for this default `Hold` behaviour?

Comment: @ilian yes `FullForm` holds and nearly works but then requires some kind of bootstrapping to rise above e.g. `FullForm@HoldForm[Dataset[Random[]]]` still shows the `HoldForm`. Be nice if the default behaviour was changed. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question is related to:

- [Prevent graphics render inside held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32296/121)
- [Returning an unevaluated expression with values substituted in](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7880/121)
- [Why doesn't "Defer" work with "TableForm"?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16664/121)
- [HoldForm does not Hold Form for fractions sometimes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69655/121)

My proposed solution:

```
mk : MakeBoxes[(Hold | HoldForm | HoldComplete | HoldPattern)[__], _] := 
 Block[{$hldDataset = True, Dataset}, mk] /; ! TrueQ[$hldDataset]
```

Now:

```
Hold[Dataset[Random[]]]
```

> ```
> Hold[Dataset[Random[]]]
> ```

Unlike the case of `Graphics` I consider the default formatting behavior pathological here.

Comment: Very neat. Thanks. Did the trick and helps improve said documentation.

Comment: Yes, definitely a bug, which has since been fixed.

Comment: @ItaiSeggev Thank you.  Do you know the specific version in which the bug was corrected?

Comment: Fixed in 11.0.0. See also [(89036)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89036/dataset-seems-to-break-information).