# Dataset seems to break Information

Tags: bugs, formatting, dataset

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 11.0.0**

*`Dataset` is new in 10.0*

---

*Note: In order to reproduce the bug, the symbol `Dataset` may need to be evaluated (to load its definitions) before defining `toDataset`.*

My little function, from pre-10.2 ,to turn a headed table into a Dataset.

```
toDataset[table_List] := 
  Dataset@(Association /@ (Function[r, Thread[First[r] -> #] & /@ Rest[r]]@table));
```

In 10.2, `??toDataset` shows something very odd indeed (after a big barf of messages).

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It appears to be something related to the head `Dataset` being on the RHS.

Comment: That is the example, the function definition itself is broken.  Its not an application of that function that breaks, its defining the function that breaks.

Comment: Yes, I've just tested on another machine and its fine.  I jumped the gun.  I may have a corrupt install.  Thanks for checking.  Except that was 10.1... doh!

Comment: Tried on 10.2 on a different machine.  When I do ??toDataset I get a spew of TextForm messages and a definition as above.  Are you sure your running this on 10.2?  Its fine on 10.1.

Comment: I really didn't get it at first.  Now I understand.  I edited the question a bit for clarity.

Comment: Sorry for confusing things with 10.1.  That is its full glory (gorey?).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem appears to be due to a v10.2 bug in the `Dataset` visualization code that generates the box form of a dataset.  It is not correctly distinguishing between `Dataset` being used as a constructor function and `Dataset` being used as the head of a constructed dataset.  It assumes the latter case unconditionally, giving the exhibited messages for the former case.

As a work-around, we can temporarily block the errant definitions while we inspect `toDataset`:

```
Block[{Dataset}, Information[toDataset]]
```

[image: information screenshot]

The defect appears to be a subtle interaction bug between `Information` and `Dataset` since expressions like the following do not exhibit the bug:

```
DownValues[toDataset]

(*
{HoldPattern[toDataset[table_List]]:>
   Dataset[Association/@Function[r,(Thread[First[r]->#1]&)/@Rest[r]][table]]}
*)
```

**Update**

The problem is more general than within the context of `Information`.  Both of the following expressions also generate many warning messages:

```
Unevaluated @ Dataset @ (* ...expr from question... *)

Defer @ Dataset @ (* ...expr from question... *)
```

Furthermore, there appears to be an evaluation leak involved:

```
Unevaluated @ Dataset[Print["leak!"]]
```

[image: evaluation leak screenshot]

```
Defer @ Dataset[Print["leak!"]]
```

[image: evaluation leak screenshot]

This behaviour is very much like what happens with `Graphics` objects.  The front-end attempts to render them in output cells, which implies evaluation:

```
Defer@Graphics[Print["leak!"]]
```

[image: Graphics leak screenshot]

We might just have to live with this behaviour in both cases (although a way to turn it off would be useful, just as the debugger allows for graphics).

Comment: Basically, evaluation control structures like `Defer` and `Unevaluated` don't apply to typesetting. Notice that `Defer @ Dataset[Print["leak!"]];` doesn't leak.

Comment: @StefanR Indeed, that was my point about the similarity to `Graphics`.  In fact, `Dataset` is a little better than `Graphics` in that it only renders when it is the outermost head.  That is why the original problem is surprising: a `Dataset` is being rendered even though it appears in a non-top-level context, namely the right-hand-side of a definition.  This is potentially dangerous, and a regression from v10.1.

Comment: I have filed an internal report to get this looked into.

Comment: @StefanR You have an incoming "feedback" email from me as well,  CASE:3391689  :)  With more details coming.

Answer (score 10):

A work around seems to be to not have Dataset as the first Head encountered...

```
toDataset[table_List]:=Dataset@@{Association/@(Function[r,Thread[First[r]->#]&/@Rest[r]]@table)};
```

So the first Head the parser sees is Apply and not Dataset.