# Error retrieving information of a package function

Tags: bugs, packages

**Bug introduced in 10.4**

---

I´m using a self written package with SortingUtilities when dealing with sorting algorithms. I use this package for more than a year or so. No I want to retrieve information on a certain function in this package via "??" and get an error message

[image: Error retrieving information]

The error occurs only on this one function in the package, all others do not show this behavior and work completely normal when retrieving information with "??". I looked a the code of the function in my package for a long time searching an error and do not see any. Here is the code to the package as a screenshot

[image: Code under suspicion]

Can anyone give me a hint what I did wrong? Sorry if it is obvious, but I do not see what is wrong here....

System: Mathematica 10.4,OS X 10.11.3

p.s.:
I provide the code also as Mathematica-Code directly from my package.

```
storeSortingTime[dataset_Dataset, (* current Dataset of timing data *) 
sortingData_List,                 (* data to be stored format {{length , time}....} *)
label_String,                     (* name of the sorting algorithm  *)
machine_String,                   (* name of the machine on which the data was calculatd *)
file_String:"timing.m"]:=         (* file to which the new Dataset has to be stored *)
Module[{rules, dsTemp, dsNew, x, y},
 rules = sortingData /.{x_,y_}-> {"length"-> x,"time"-> y};
 rules = Append[#,"machine" -> machine]& /@ rules;
 dsTemp = Dataset@(Association@@@rules);
 dsTemp = Append[#,"algorithm" -> label] & /@ dsTemp;
 dsNew=Union[dataset,dsTemp];
 Export[file,dsNew];
 dsNew
]
```

Comment: This is very puzzling. It is also interesting to note that `?storeSortingTime` barfs up the same errors, while `Definition[storeSortingTime]` works fine, although `Definition` should be explicitly equivalent to `?`. On the other hand, `Information` returns the same result as `??`, i.e. the errors seen above.

Comment: Have you recently upgraded to a newer version of MMA?

Comment: @MarcoB: Yes I did the latest update when 10.4 was available. I am currently on a business trip but at home I have also 10.3 and can try it out at the weekend.

Comment: That would be great! I am very curious to see how far back this goes.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [Dataset seems to break Information](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89036/142).

Comment: @WReach, how very odd. It's broken in 10.2, seems to be okay in 10.3, and now apparently broken again in 10.4. One wonders...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug connected with the presence of a `Dataset` expression in your function. (I am on *Mathematica* v. 10.4 on Win7-64).

You can see the failure in a simpler example:

```
Clear[f]
f[a_] := Dataset@a
```

`Definition` of this function returns:

```
Definition[f]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which looks weird to me: I would not have expected the `Dataset` to be evaluated to that graphical representation in the definition.

I would think that it is this attempt to create the graphical representation that is sending MMA into a tailspin here.

I would be interested in hearing if this behavior is new to v. 10.4 (I have just upgraded and don't have access to previous versions myself).

Using `?`, `Information`, or `??` all return the same errors you see; for instance:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This seems to be a good explanation, I have also seen the attempt of the system regarding the processing of an Image. I´m going to report that to WR, for the moment I´m pleased that it had not been an obvious mistake made by myself ;-)

Comment: On 10.3, the `Dataset[]` does not evaluate with either `Definition[]` or `Information[]`. This might be a new bug indeed.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for checking. Ilian added the bugs tag, so I'll go ahead and add a header indicating that the bug was probably introduced in 10.4.